# How to make a select to place records one below the other with respect to each other

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to pivot my table as shown below:

[image]
DATA

Comment: This is a bit of a cryptical question. Do you want to make a sort? Or a hierachical query?

Comment: Please add to the description explaining the issue in a bit more detail. I'm not sure what transformation the images are showing. Is it a pivot? I added my guess because I edited the post to make the images inline instead of a link, and SO required some text.

Answer (score 1):

```
with tab_one as (
    select 'REG_000' reg_father, 150 vlr, 1 id_father, 'REG_001' reg_son, 50 vlr_son, 1 id_son from dual
    union all
    select 'REG_000' reg_father, 150 vlr, 1 id_father, 'REG_001' reg_son, 50 vlr_son, 2 id_son from dual
    union all
    select 'REG_000' reg_father, 150 vlr, 1 id_father, 'REG_001' reg_son, 50 vlr_son, 3 id_son from dual
    union all
    select 'REG_000' reg_father, 60 vlr, 2 id_father, 'REG_001' reg_son, 30 vlr_son, 4 id_son from dual
    union all
    select 'REG_000' reg_father, 60 vlr, 2 id_father, 'REG_001' reg_son, 30 vlr_son, 5 id_son from dual
)
select * from
(
    select distinct reg_father reg, vlr, id_father id, id_father fid from tab_one
    union all
    select reg_son reg, vlr_son vlr, id_son id, id_father fid from tab_one
)
order by fid, id
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cf3bc77f40b6a8ea734d4f2ebaab06c)